# Python split a string containing a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to split a line from a file, but got stuck.
Let's say i have this line in my file:

> John, Smith, 1580, ["cool","line","splitting"]

Now I tried to make this:

```
line = line.split(',')
print line
```

Of course it returns:

> ['John', ' Smith', ' 1580', ' ["cool"', '"line"', '"splitting"]']

The problem is the list from file. I can't read it properly. I want it to look something like:

> ['John', 'Smith', 1580, ["cool", "line", "splitting"]]

Can someone help me do it this way?

Comment: something like that or that? Python 2 or Python 3

Comment: exactly that and python 2.7

Comment: Will the input data change? like will you have `John Smith Frank 1580` ?

Comment: No, it won't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
import re
line = 'John, Smith, 1580, ["cool","line","splitting"]'
final_line = [ast.literal_eval(i) if i.startswith('[') else int(i) if re.findall('^\d+$', i) else i for i in re.split(',\s*', line)]
```

Output:

```
['John', 'Smith', 1580, ['cool', 'line', 'splitting']]
```

Comment: :D and 1580 needs to be an integer

Comment: line[2] = int(line[2]), that's easy :)

Comment: Hate to be the party pooper but a bit too whitespace dependent for comfort.

Comment: Let's say there were no spaces. How would you do that?

Comment: @Nirod please see my recent edit. I changed the regular expression in `re.split` so that the `\s` is optional (`\s*`)