# how to split a string containing more than one list? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Hi Im having trouble while reading a file and trying to split a string that has 2 lists.

I have this string in the file text:

**BaseDeDatos.txt:**

```py
hello test, C, ['Gore', 'Family'], 3.4, Actor, ['Cesar', 'Mile'], 1
```

**Code:**

```py
with open('BaseDeDatos.txt', 'r') as data:
        peli = data.readlines()[int(modificar_peli)-1]
        selec_final = [ast.literal_eval(i) if i.startswith('[') else int(i) if re.findall('^\\d+$', i) else i for i in re.split(',\s*', peli)]
```

As suggested from another question: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47481361/python-split-a-string-containing-a-list) I tried using `ast.literal_eval()` but im getting this error:

```py
return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,  File "<unknown>", line 1
    ['Gore'
          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

**Output Expected:**

```py
["hello test", "C", "['Gore', 'Family']", "3.4", "Actor", "['Cesar', 'Mile']", "1"]
```

If it helps I tried using the same code when I had only 1 list and it split it perfectly.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: what is the output that you are expecting ?

Comment: @Gary ["hello test", "C", "['Gore', 'Family']", "3.4", "Actor", "['Cesar', 'Mile']", "1"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
s = "hello test, C, ['Gore', 'Family'], 3.4, Actor, ['Cesar', 'Mile'], 1"

splitted = re.split(r', (?!\')', s)
```

This will split the line on `,`(comma and space) only if there is no single-quote `'` after slit expression. More about lookahead syntax: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-21

Output:

```
['hello test',
 'C',
 "['Gore', 'Family']",
 '3.4',
 'Actor',
 "['Cesar', 'Mile']",
 '1']
```